# Before calling createChannel, do I need to call Channel.Open method?

Tags: wcf

As title. Is Open method necessary before calling CreateChannel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF Channel has many states (created,opened, closed,..) , before opening the chanel it must be created , it's the role of CreateChannel methodand after you can open it, but with WCF the channel is opened implicitly if some method of proxy created by CreateChanel is invocked.

And sure you can invoke Open explicitly but after creation;